# how to prevent windows from shutting down using c#?

Tags: c#

I am making a desktop application using c# in which i have to prevent the computer from shutting down in some conditions.

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell("shutdown -a", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, false, -1);
```

this command is not running in my visual studio 2012. Try to give a better solution. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Prevent shutdown c#](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx)

#### Else do =>

- Create Application.ApplicationExit Event and execute ('shutdown -a')